# CentOS NFS client can't read a big size NFS file

Tags: linux, nfsv4

NFS server CentOS 7.5
NFS client CentOS 7.2

Client can read 4KB NFS file,however can't read big file such as 20GB.
when issue a command to show the big file, the process would be uninterruptible.

```
root     23099  0.0  0.0 110136   812 pts/84   D+   15:05   0:00 more part-00000-48d29bb1-f039-4fcb-b42b-3fe5f51c6429-c000.txt
```

Client memory:

```
      # free -g
                  total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
    Mem:            251         150           1           0          99          99
    Swap:            19          17           2
```

client cpu utilization at 10%

```
01:00:01 PM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
01:10:01 PM     all      3.95      0.00      0.76      2.53      0.00     92.77
01:20:01 PM     all      3.06      0.00      0.64      2.63      0.00     93.67
01:30:01 PM     all      3.17      0.00      0.57      2.85      0.00     93.41
01:40:02 PM     all      3.06      0.00      0.57      2.89      0.00     93.48
01:50:01 PM     all      4.80      0.00      1.20      2.96      0.00     91.04
02:00:01 PM     all      2.80      0.00      0.63      2.86      0.00     93.72
02:10:01 PM     all      4.37      0.00      0.93      2.79      0.00     91.92
02:20:01 PM     all      4.42      0.00      1.97      2.81      0.00     90.80
```

Client mount parameters:

```
*.*.*.*:/file on /file1 type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=*.*.*.*,local_lock=none,addr=*.*.*.*)
```